# Building Android application through command prompt

Tags: android, ant

I am trying to build this code to a .apk file : https://github.com/CodeMonkeyzDevelopment/platform_packages_apps_mms/tree/gingerbread-release through the command prompt. I am following these instructions: http://developer.android.com/tools/building/building-cmdline.html but when I navigate to the project directory and type 'ant debug' it returns this error:

```
    Buildfile: build.xml does not exist!
    Build failed
```

I'm confused, if anyone wants to have a go feel free, the repository should be up to date. I'm just confused to as why this isn't working, so I'd be happy to have some help :)

Thanks!! :)

Answer (score 1):

You first need to create the build.xml with

```
android update project --name <project_name> --target <target_ID> --path <path_to_your_project>
```

Check out the Setting up projects documentation, Updating a Project section, http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/projects-cmdline.html#UpdatingAProject

Comment: I tried to do that, following the steps on the site. However, I tried 'android list targets', which brought the error: 'android: command not found.' I had the 'tools' folder in the command prompt as well

Comment: Well, I got it to work, I needed to put a './' in front of the 'android'. However, I'm getting errors, which is a bit weird for code straight from the android github page. If anyone wants to have a look, feel free to :)